# Maven and server deploy plugin (WebSphere maybe Jboss too)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, websphere

I using eclipse with websphere. I have the websphere plugin and a server configurated.

My project uses maven for dependency resolution.

The problem is that wen i deploy to server, it deploys via the eclipse build, and exports the maven dependencys marked as TEST scope.

I think its because in the deployment assembly the maven directory is marked for export, but if i remove this all dependencys go away...

How can I configure eclipse to not export the maven TEST scope dependencys??

Ok, here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.gov.serpro</groupId>
<artifactId>tratamento</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name></name>
<description></description>
<url></url>
<parent>
    <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoiselle-jsf-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</parent>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>serpro.ui.internal</id>
        <name>Repositório de Componentes Visuais - SERPRO</name>
        <url>http://archiva.desenv.serpro/repository/ui-internal</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>serpro.ui.snapshot</id>
        <name>Repositório de Componentes Visuais - SERPRO</name>
        <url>http://archiva.desenv.serpro/repository/ui-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>demoiselle.sourceforge.net-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/repository/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jsf</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.serpro.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>componente-visual-rfb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.weblets</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblets-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.weblets</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblets-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-junit</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

So here the dependency demoiselle-junit is marked as TEST scope, but when i publish or export via eclipse it is exported in the .war file, with all the jars that come with it, including weld, and that makes the app to crash when loading...

Comment: Would be helpful if you post your relevant pom.xml

Comment: Mark your dependencies as "provided" if you require them on compile time but you don't want they go inside the EAR: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Provided won't work too... It's the same case....

Comment: I don't know much about Eclipse (stopped using it years ago) but if it doesn't understand how to deploy it properly, maybe you can use the Maven Cargo plugin for deployment instead. However there is something very wrong with your setup if things that are in `test`or `provided` scope still end up in the target war/ear (the one that Maven generates anyway).

Comment: check this post "How to exclude a Maven test-scoped dependency from Eclipse": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426957/how-to-exclude-a-maven-test-scoped-dependency-from-eclipse-but-keep-it-in-the-p

Comment: ...and let us know... (As for me, after being struck with too many Eclipse's maven bugs, I'm using netbeans 7.4 where it comes out-of-the box in a working setup)

Comment: Nope, with kepler the plugin is already there.... Qhats work (sort of) is creating a build config war:war and in the "Deployment Assembly" I exported the /target/{my webapp}. And when I make a change in any file I call the build again.... Perhaps if i can run the maven build automatically whenever I save a file (will see if this is possible)